# SVG animateMotion (calcMode spline) not working in FF and Safari

Tags: animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I want to move a circle along a path inside an svg with different easing. I wanted to use [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion) but have never used it before. Using JS is not an option in this case.

It works fine in Chrome and Opera, but not in Safari and Firefox.

```
<animateMotion 
    dur="4s" 
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    calcMode="spline" 
    keySplines="0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1 ; 0.3 0 1 1"
    keyTimes="0 ; 0.3 ; 0.6 ; 1"
    path="M54,183.8c0-86.5,128.5-87.2,128.5,0c0-86.5,116.9-87.2,116.9,0c0-86.5,115.1-87.2,115.1,0
    c0-86.5,55.5-123.5,55.5,111" />
```

If I remove `calcMode`, `keySplines` and `keyTimes` it works in all browsers.

I would also appreciate any alternative solution for moving an element on rounded curves with different easings.

Comment: You might include your whole attempt, I see [it working in the other browsers mentioned](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/PowOEbE?&editable=true) but there's definitely something wonky between your `keysplines` and `keytimes`.

Comment: Your example code does not work in Safari (12) and is choppy in FF (71).
Here's my reduced code: https://jsfiddle.net/7axr6qf3/
If I replace the path with the path you used, it also works in FF, but still not in SF.
So can be sth. wrong with the past?

Comment: Ya I don't use safari for anything so didn't test it. Will swing back and take another peek here shortly, still technically a work day for me also :D

Comment: Your comment already pushed me a good direction, searching for specific Safari issues, but still can't see any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

I figured out, that two things were independently from each other creating the issue:

1. Safari does not accept spaces between KeyTimes Values (all other browsers do, and Safari also does within KeySplines).
2. Firefox seems to need one more value for `KeyTimes` and `KeySplines`. So I added one value to each line.

Fixed Code:

```
keySplines="0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1"
keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.6;1"
```

Full Example:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <circle r="13.5" fill="black">
      <animateMotion 
       dur="4s" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       calcMode="spline" 
        keySplines="0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1 ; 0 0 0.5 1"
       keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.6;1"
        path="M54,183.8c0-86.5,128.5-87.2,128.5,0c0-86.5,116.9-87.2,116.9,0c0-86.5,115.1-87.2,115.1,0c0-86.5,55.5-123.5,55.5,111" />
   </circle>
   <path stroke="red" fill="none" d="M54,183.8c0-86.5,128.5-87.2,128.5,0c0-86.5,116.9-87.2,116.9,0c0-86.5,115.1-87.2,115.1,0c0-86.5,55.5-123.5,55.5,111"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```